# Javascript wont run in any other browser besides IE. Why?

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue getting this to work in firefox, android OS, and other browsers. Anyone know why? I have tried different parses and I have looked at a bunch of docs including https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest

```
function callNews()
{
   var url = "someUrlHere";
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var xmlDoc = null;

for (var i = 1; i < 20; i++)
{

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml'); 
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

    var url2 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("link")[i].textContent;
    var newsTitle = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[i].textContent;
    var des = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("description")[i].textContent;
    //var newsDate = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("pubDate")[i].textContent;
    document.getElementById("desc" + i).innerHTML = newsTitle + "<br /><i style=\"color:red;\">" + des + "</i><br /><a href=\"" + url2 + "\">" + url2 + "</a>" + "<br /><br />" + "<iframe src=\"https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.website.com\"scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\"style=\"border:none; width:450px; height:80px\"></iframe>";
    xmlhttp.send();
}

document.getElementById("desc" + 1).innerHTML = "Testing";
}
```

updated the code... still not working

Comment: It would help if you add the error you are getting.

Comment: `<i style="color:red;">` - that smells. `<em class="des">` seems better.

Comment: oh, that status code is 0

Comment: You are setting the same `innerHTML` to the same element in both branches of the `if`. Don't Repeat Yourself.

Comment: What is `xmlDoc`? HTML doesn't define the tags `description`, `title` and `link` in the way you seem to use them.

Comment: You don't seem to use the response in any way.

Comment: I have updated the code with the correct syntax. it works in all versions of IE but no other browser

Comment: @Spontaneous1980 — See Bjorn's comment. Look at the JavaScript console of the other browsers you are testing in. What does it say?

Comment: [11:43:22.894] Unknown property 'text-wrap'.  Declaration dropped. @ localhost

Comment: that was for css... however, there are no errors that come up

Comment: Why is the send() call inside the loop? Don't you want to send first, then loop through the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked even better for me

```
function callNews()
{
var url = "urlGoesHere";

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    alert("Old");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title");
var d = document.createElement("div");
var news = new Array();
var word = "";
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
{
    news[i] = "<a href=\"" + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("link")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "\" style=\"text-decoration:none;\"  >" + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</a>";
    news[i] = "<b>" + news[i] + "</b><br /><em style=color:#555;> " + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("description")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</em>";
    word = word + " " + news[i] + "<br /><br />"
}
document.getElementById("newsUpdate0").innerHTML = word;
}
```